# Laravel text views doesn't work woth ucwords

Tags: php, laravel-blade, uppercase

I am new in Laravel

When I open a project from internet, some of the text shows the text with the addition word .

example : in sidebar menu, the text (menu) displayed is **'sidebar.job_vacancy'**.
The text should be display **'Job Vacancy'** . ;

My blade file is

```
....
<li class="nav-item {{ menu_active('job.vacancy.*') }}">
                <a href="{{route('job.vacancy.list', ['role' => user_role()])}}">
                    <i class="far fa-newspaper"></i>
                    <p>{{ ucwords(__('sidebar.job_vacancy')) }}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
....
```

And it refers to file in .....(my_project)\resources\lang\en\sidebar.php

```
return [
....
'job_vacancy' => 'job vacancy',
....
]
```

It has 2 support language, ID and EN
After receiving some qlue, i have changed my ENV

```
APP_LOCALE=id
APP_LOCALES=en,id
APP_FALLBACK_LOCALE=id,en
APP_TIMEZONE='Asia/Jakarta'
MULTI_LANGUAGE=true
CDN_BASE_URL="http://localhost/iccn/public/"
```

But this is still not working

Comment: Maybe you selected a lang whcih you dont support with a translation.

Comment: The issue is with `__('sidebar.job_vacancy')`, not ucwords. You can test it by doing `__('sidebar.job_vacancy')` without the ucwords, and it will still print `sidebar.job_vacancy`. As Maik said, make sure that the language you've selected has the string, or make sure that the [fallback_locale is `en`](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/localization#configuring-the-locale)

Comment: Hi @aynber , thank you for your response. I have changed my ENV (check the question that i changed), but this is still the same.

Comment: I think the fallback_locale can be only 1 language, possibly `app_locales` as well. What does the `fallback_locale` look like in your config/app.php?

Comment: @B-Azhari can you try to use the trans(9 helper function? `{{ trans('sidebar.job_vacancy') }}` and dont forget to run `php artisan config:cache`after you change the .env file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are using a language that you do not support in your language. This means that Laravel will display the key from your translation help if Laravel cannot find a translation for the current language. Please have a look in your folder `\resources\lang\{your-lang}\sidebar.php` if the file exists.if not, create it and then it will work with the ucfirst() function.

Comment: @B-Azhari dont forget `php artisan config:cache` after you change the .env file

Comment: thankyou. it is solved

Comment: @B-Azhari you welcome and many thanks for your feedback! It works after clearing the cache and config?